# Using 'extern' inside class gives me 'storage class specified' error

Tags: c++, class, extern

I'm trying to use "Graph" variable globally.

I have no problem defining it in class without 'extern',
but when I add 'extern', it gives following error.
What's wrong and right way to use it?
Thank you.

Error message I got :

```
 error: storage class specified for ‘g2_’
                 extern Graph    g2_;
                                 ^~~
```

Header File :

```
namespace ompl
{
    namespace geometric
    {
        class AAA: public PRM   
        {
        public:
                        
            typedef boost::adjacency_list <
                boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
                boost::property < vertex_state_t, base::State*,
                boost::property < vertex_total_connection_attempts_t, unsigned long int,
                boost::property < vertex_successful_connection_attempts_t, unsigned long int,
                boost::property < boost::vertex_predecessor_t, unsigned long int,
                boost::property < boost::vertex_rank_t, unsigned long int > > > > >,
                boost::property < boost::edge_weight_t, base::Cost >
            > Graph;

            extern Graph    g2_;
        };
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: You cannot have an `extern` in a class. How would that work? `extern` says that the variable is defined elsewhere, but members of a class cannot be defined except in the class itself.

Comment: You probably meant to make it a `static` member (since you are talking about using it "globally")?

Comment: @UnholySheep yea, but as long as I know you cannot change the content of 'static'? so I was just looking for way to defining it as a global variable. but if 'static' could be used as global way it doesn't matter

Comment: You can definitely change the content of a static variable. Static is not the same as const. Static just means that the content of the variable is not attached to a specific instance of the class, but shared by all instances.

Comment: @CodyGray oh I was confused. sorry. would it work if I try using 'static'?

Comment: You can certainly create static members of classes. Whether that will work for you, I cannot say, as you do not tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: People often misuse `static` because their object model is flawed. There should only be very few cases where you really need `static` member variables. Mixing object oriented programming with static members (aka global state) can result in messy and complicated code. Maybe you can try find a way to do without global state?